# Joined dataview list count based on filter - sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part, usage-counters

I have a DataView Webpart that displays a set of list items (articles). In each item(article) being displayed, I want to show a counter of items from another list that are linked to the unique ID of the first list. My second list consists of comments. Essentially I want to have a comment counter per article.

Thank you in advance for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, this is provided for you OOTB with SharePoint.  There is a lookup column that will produce the `Count Related` of related items.  Take a look here at this article for more in depth details, however, it'll be fairly straightforward to set up.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150116112920/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/jackiebo/archive/2007/02/23/lookup-count-related-the-magic-behind-sharepoint-s-comments-column.aspx)